# decoding an encrypted text with modulo

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, cryptography

> ```
> A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J  K  L  M  N  O
> 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13 14 15
>
> P  Q  R  S  T  U  V  W  X  Y  Z  Ä  Ö  Ü  ß
> 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 00
> ```

A encryption method relates a letter Ω to letter $Δ\equiv aΩ + d$ $(mod 30)$ with $a, d\in {\Bbb N}$.
$gcd(a, 30) = 1$

Decode following text:
PXFHKAR ARXHKAR XßIJKAR

Any hints how to decode it?

Comment: Well there is the obvious brute force method. Find all possible $a$'s, find all possible $d$'s and then try all possible decryptions to see which produces meaningful text.

Comment: Is the plaintext known to be German? If so, I would make some educated guesses as to which two(three)-letter combination is a frequent end of the word. Match those (3)2 letters with (K)AR in your ciphertext. Then form the related system of two congruences, and solve that system. If the first guess didn't work, try another one. Theoretical buzzword: *frequency analysis*

Comment: I don't know if the plain text is in German, but I guess so. I will try it with the KAR letters!

Comment: Do you happen to go to the University of Ulm?  Brute force works, it seems.  (Oh, and the plain text is in Latin.)

Comment: Hmm. The ciphertext is grouped into sequences of 7 letters. I guess it was premature of me to assume they would correspond to complete words. Frequency analysis still probably works, but scratch what I said about endings of words.

Comment: @Rebecca Yes, going to this one! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I "brute forced" it.  We apply all $k\Delta+c \pmod {30}$ for $k,c \in \{0,1,\ldots,29\}$ and $k$ coprime to $30$.  This gives $8 \times 30$ items to inspect.  I inspected the list, and it turns out $k=13$ and $c=21$ works.

Comment: With those values i'm getting: RBHDMCN CNBDMCN BTQTMCN Can this be right?

Comment: Oops!  No, we should add 21, not 20 (it's just an artifact from my code).  (RBHDMCN -> SCIENDO etc.)

Answer (score 1):

This is an affine cipher. This is a simple substitution cipher and  in general is cryptalanyzed with [frequency analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_analysis_%28cryptanalysis%29).

$\Delta = a\Omega+d (\text{mod}30)\Rightarrow \Delta-d=a\Omega(\text{mod}30)$.
Since $\text{gcd}(a,30)=1$, $a$ has an inverse $a^{-1}$ modulo 30. So, $$ \Omega = a^{-1}(\Delta-d)(\text{mod}30)$$

Here, $\Omega$ is a plaintext digit and $\Delta$ is its corresponding ciphertext digit. So, you have an equation with which from ciphertext you can find the plaintext. If you find two (*plainletter*, *cryptoletter*) pairs, then you can solve the equation and find $a$ and $d$.

For each language there is a [letter frequency table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_frequencies). I guess that the plaintext in question is in German. What you have to do now is to count how many times each cipherletter appears on the ciphertext. The one with most appearances **might** correspond to the plainletter with highest frequency in German (which is "e"). So, once you have a pair (e,*some cryptoletter*), you can do the same for the next most frequent letter in German. **Attention**, that this might not give you the solution for sure, especially when the ciphertext is as short as yours. You might need to make many trials or notice patterns, too. For example, the "KAR" sequence appears a lot! Can you think of a corresponding plaintext for this sequence?